# Why can I start a bounty only after 1 week?

Tags: support, bounties, rate-limiting

One of my questions had not so good answers and I would start a bounty right now.

Why do I have to wait so long?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the FAQ

```
Questions must be at least 2 days old to be eligible for a bounty.
```

so I think that it is actually two days that you have to wait. I believe that the reason is to give people a chance to respond before putting a bounty on it. If you believe that your question is too far down the main page try editing it if you have more information and that will bump it up.